# issue in tranferring data from host machine to guest machine

Tags: linux, centos, file-transfer

We are having one Dell PowerConnect Switch which is operated on 10 Gbps; in which six to seven Server machines are connected . In each server machine we have inserted externally one 10 Gbps Lan card .In one of these server machine we have installed Centos-6.4 (64bit) as base OS also using oracle virtual box-4.2.16 (64bit) we have installed one Centos-6.2(64bit) virtual machine (with virtual box guest addition). My issue is If i transfer one file having size of only 60-62 MB from other server machine to the server machine in which VM we installed;data transferred very fastly within 2-3 seconds with avg speed 50-52MBps but i transfer the same amount of data from other server machine to the same above mentioned Virtual machine we saw data transfer with speed of avg 6-12 KBps.

If i perform the reverse process i.e. transfer data of same size 60-62 MB from this Virtual Machine to other physical server machine data get tranfered very fastly.

Please suggest if any one know about this issue

Comment: What network type is your VM configured for (NAT, Bridged, etc)? Are the speed and duplex settings in the VM correct (ethtool)? If you are using Bridged, does your switch match the NIC? Did you install the virtual box extensions in the host, as well as the guest additions?

Comment: Thanks Frank for your reply ; i did all things as you mentioned i.e. Bridged;speed;Full duplex;Guest addition;extensions. But still facing an issue

Comment: today i did one more thing i took separate laptop which is operated in 100Mbps. I disconnected one server (in which Vrtual machine installed) from switch; then connect back-to-back network cable from this server machine to laptop machine (keeping server machine virtual machine and laptop machine in same network) then i found the same above mentioned issue i.e. data transfer of size 60-62 MB from laptop to server is occured at 5MBps but data (of same size) transfer from laptop machine to virtual machine occured at avg 4-5 KBps

Comment: issue has been resolved by creating briged network in Host machine;